# Adding an object to Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I know how to add JButton to a JPanel but how about a class I make?

I have this class:

```
public class Monster
{
    private ImageIcon monster;
    private JButton b;

    public Monster()
    {
        monster = new ImageIcon("Monster.jpg");
        b = new JButton(monster);
        b.setIcon(monster);
    }
}
```

I have another class and in that class I want to add the icon to my swing window.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class GameWindow
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private Monster monster;

    public GameWindow()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();
        monster = new Monster();

        panel.add(monster); 

        frame.setContentPane(panel); 
        frame.setTitle("Game"); 
        frame.setSize(400,400); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The panal.add() method works for JButtons but not for my Monster class. How can I add my Monster object to the Swing window I made in GameWindow class?

Comment: Why not have a class that extends `JButton`?

Comment: You can make your class extends JComponent and add the two elements into it !

Comment: don't to extend, return this Object, search for inherintace v.s. composition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Swing components.  The only reason to extend a Swing component (or any other Java class) is if you want to override one of the class methods.

You were missing a method in your Monster class.

```
public class Monster
{
    private ImageIcon monster;
    private JButton b;

    public Monster()
    {
        monster = new ImageIcon("Monster.jpg");
        b = new JButton(monster);
        b.setIcon(monster);
    }

    public JButton getMonsterButton() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

The add line in your GameWindow class would look like this:

```
    panel.add(monster.getMonsterButton());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, since `JPanel` accepts a `Swing UI` Components, this makes your class `MonsterIcon` a part of Swing (in lay man's term)

```
public class MonsterIcon extends JButton {

      public MonsterIcon () {
        this(new ImageIcon("Monster.jpg"));
      }

      public MonsterIcon (ImageIcon icon) {
        setIcon(icon);
        setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        setIconTextGap(0);
        setBorderPainted(false);
        setBorder(null);
        setText(null);
        setSize(icon.getImage().getWidth(null), icon.getImage().getHeight(null));
      }
 }
```

Comment: This works except that the icon is not showing. I only get a very small blank JButton.

Comment: Since you are extending a jbutton, you don't need a `private JButton b;` sentence, use `this.setIcon... `

Comment: That's what I was missing. Thanks sgmart and all.

Comment: Rather than _extending_ `JButton`, consider a factory method that creates and _returns_ a `JButton`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your class extend `ImageIcon` or `JButton`. This is because the `add()` method of the `JPanel` expects a `JComponent`.